# Meteor : filter a publication on a nested property

Tags: javascript, mongodb, collections, meteor

I have a simple publication :

`return Companies.find({}, {fields: {'myField1': 1, 'myField2': 1}});`

In my `Companies` collections, for each company I have an array `customers` and an array `managers`. Those array contains objects with '_id' and various other property.

For visualization, an new company might be added as follows:

```
Companies.insert({
  customers: [{_id: <userId>, otherProp: <data>}, ...],
  managers: [{_id: <userId>, otherProp: <data>}, ...]
});
```

This `_id` field is the id of the corresponding user in the users collection.

I would like to return only the companies where you can find the _id of the user in one of the objects of the customers array (or the managers array, depending of the user).

This is probably a mongo question, but I'm not sure.
=> in the documentation, they mentions the mongo selectors : http://docs.meteor.com/#selectors
( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ ) But I cannot figure out how to use that for my case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I appears that you can simply do :

`Companies.find({'customers._id': this.userId}, {fields: {'stores': 1, 'customers': 1}});`

This will search inside the array.

But now, how to finish the filter and return only the customer's informations and not the informations of all the company's customer ?

And the answer is in the mongo doc again !

I appears that you can add a projection on a field.
( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#proj._S_elemMatch )

The final request with the proper filters is :
`return Companies.find({'customers._id': this.userId}, {fields: {'stores': 1, 'customers': { $elemMatch: { _id: this.userId } }}});`

(I was not that hard in the end, but if my answer can help someone... :) )

Comment: Note that the "final request" will not work on the client side in Meteor because `$elemMatch` is not yet implemented in minimongo.

Comment: @fabien Excellent answer but i have a small query. What if my object attribute names are dynamic ? Is there any way to query in that case ?
For ex in you answer what if i don't have 'customer' attribute predefined in  customer._id ?